# Hiding annotations while panning or zooming in Oxyplot

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

I have an Oxyplot model with about 500 ArrowAnnotations. This has a really bad performance when panning or zooming.

I'd like to disable rendering of the annotations while in pan mode and while zooming.

How can I do this?

So far I created a class deriving from ArrowAnnotation and overriding Render() method. Within the Render method I want to decide if to render or not.